# Getting issue at the time of receving check box value : Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get the value of value of check box but i checked on checkbox get the value as true and false but i don't want this.

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-warning">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.industries" ng-init="search.industries = i.name" value="{{i.name}}" class="styled" id="industry-{{i.id}}" data-taggable="1" data-tag-id="i-agriculture-fisheries-plantation">
                            {{search.industries | json}}
     <label for="industry-{{i.id}}">{{i.name}}</label>
</div>
```

I just want to get the value whatever i'm getting in {{i.name}} . and i have tried it by using these line of code but still getting value as true n false.

Please help me to get this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I'm trying to get the value of value of check box` - where are your trying to get it? Where is your code?

Comment: A checkbox actually is made for giving true or false values. What do you want to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get the json. when i clicked on checkbox ,in json it's displaying true and when i unchecked it ,getting false.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input[checkbox]

Comment: @Nikolaus..i just want when i clicked on checked ,i got the whatever i'm getting in value attribute , in ng-model.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`value="{{search.industries = i.name}}"`

If above way does not works, then try this below code

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-warning">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.industries" ng-init="search.industries = i.name" value="{{i.name}}" class="styled" id="industry-{{i.id}}" ng-change="stateChanged(i.name)" data-taggable="1" data-tag-id="i-agriculture-fisheries-plantation">
                            {{search.industries | json}}
     <label for="industry-{{i.id}}">{{i.name}}</label>
</div>


//js
$scope.stateChanged = function (name) {
       $scope.search.industries=name;
       alert(name);
}
```

Comment: this line doesn't work for me.cz by using i'm unable to clicked on checkbox.

Comment: @dev_02  `i'm unable to clicked on checkbox` Then why are you using checkbox? you can go with label right?